# P tag is not displayed in html editor (TinyMCE) for WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce

I am developing site with WordPress and I'm newbie for WordPress. WP adds `<p>` tag in editor while adding any post or pages. But I can't see the `<p>` tag in HTML mode. 
Can anyone suggest me what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: wordpress doesn't add it automatically. Why do u need it?

Comment: Thank you Shoban!!! I can't see p tag in html mode. I just want to make it visible in html mode. Is it possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not difficult to do this. To display the p and br tag we just need to install plugin which is "tinymce-advanced" and do some setting change. To change the setting just click check box for "**`Stop removing the p and br tags when saving and show them in HTML editor`**" and save. Now we can see the p and br tags in HTML mode.

:)

Comment: You can mark your own answer as "accepted", so if people search for this same problem in SO they will know there's already a provided solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that plugin it works but <p> and <br> not displaying in a database. I fired query on wp_post table for post content at that time they not showing <p> and <br> tag can you please help me into this?

Answer (score 14):

When you retrieve the stored data from the database, you need to run a filter on it to add the p and br tags back in. This is how wordpress handles content. When you use the_content(), for example, it is already running a filter on it, so when you have a custom loop, you may need to run the filter manually.

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $your_retrieved_data); ?>
```

reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

You definitely don't need a plugin, and I would recommend not using the method described by user75472. Your data won't be as clean and future-proof.

Comment: It works for me, but with `<?php` output will not be happen. It should be replaced with `<?=`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line just before the_content() tag in your template:

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

[Source](http://folkspants.com/blog/remove-paragraph-tags-from-your-wordpress-posts-so-your-media-stays-put)